# Smooks XML to XML Conversion - Issue with sequence of the XML structure

Tags: java, xml, smooks

I am trying to convert below XML in to the another XML using Smooks config and the sequence of the Order_header and Order_line are not appearing as expected, I tried shuffling the freemaker sections up and down and nothing worked.

**Source XML structure**

```
<Order>
 <Order_Header>
  <OrdNumber>1</OrdNumber>
  <CustomerName>ABC</CustomerName>
   <Order_Line>
    <ItemCode>Item1</ItemCode>
    <ItemDesc>Item A</ItemDesc>
    <Quantity>2</Quantity>
   </Order_Line>
   <Order_Line>
    <ItemCode>Item2</ItemCode>
    <ItemDesc>Item B</ItemDesc>
    <Quantity>1</Quantity>
   </Order_Line>
  </Order_Header>
  <Order_Header>
  <OrdNumber>2</OrdNumber>
  <CustomerName>XYZ</CustomerName>
   <Order_Line>
    <ItemCode>Item1</ItemCode>
    <ItemDesc>Item A</ItemDesc>
    <Quantity>2</Quantity>
   </Order_Line>
   <Order_Line>
    <ItemCode>Item2</ItemCode>
    <ItemDesc>Item B</ItemDesc>
    <Quantity>1</Quantity>
   </Order_Line>
    <Order_Line>
    <ItemCode>Item3</ItemCode>
    <ItemDesc>Item C</ItemDesc>
    <Quantity>1</Quantity>
   </Order_Line>
  </Order_Header>
  </Order>
```

**Expected Output XML**

```
<ORDERS>
    <STRUCTTYPE TYPE="1">
        <DEFAULTS>      
            <DIRECT>2</DIRECT>
            <DOCTYPE>ORDERS05</DOCTYPE>         
        </DEFAULTS>     
          <ONUM>1</ONUM>
          <CNAME>ABC</CNAME>
           <OLINE>
            <ITEM>Item1</ITEM>          
            <QTY>2</QTY>
           </OLINE>
           <OLINE>
            <ITEM>Item2</ITEM>
            <DESC>Item B</DESC>
            <QTY>1</QTY>
           </OLINE>
          <ONUM>2</ONUM>
          <CNAME>XYZ</CNAME>
           <OLINE>
            <ITEM>Item1</ITEM>          
            <QTY>2</QTY>
           </OLINE>
           <OLINE>
            <ITEM>Item2</ITEM>          
            <QTY>1</QTY>
           </OLINE>
            <OLINE>
            <ITEM>Item3</ITEM>          
            <QTY>1</QTY>
           </OLINE>     
    </STRUCTTYPE>
</ORDERS>
```

**My Smooks Configuration**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <smooks-resource-list xmlns="http://www.milyn.org/xsd/smooks-1.1.xsd"
                          xmlns:core="http://www.milyn.org/xsd/smooks/smooks-core-1.3.xsd"
                          xmlns:ftl="http://www.milyn.org/xsd/smooks/freemarker-1.1.xsd">

        <core:filterSettings type="SAX" defaultSerialization="false" />

        <resource-config selector="orders,order_header,order_line">
            <resource>org.milyn.delivery.DomModelCreator</resource>
        </resource-config>

         <ftl:freemarker applyOnElement="orders">
            <ftl:template><!--

                <ORDERS>
                    <STRUCTTYPE TYPE="1">
                        <DEFAULTS>
                            <DIRECT>2</DIRECT>
                            <DOCTYPE>ORDERS05</DOCTYPE>
                        </DEFAULTS>
                        <OHEADER>
                            <?TEMPLATE-SPLIT-PI?>
                        <OHEADER>

                    </STRUCTTYPE>
                </ORDERS>
                --></ftl:template>
        </ftl:freemarker>

        <ftl:freemarker applyOnElement="order_header">
            <ftl:template><!--
                        <ONUM>${order_header.OrdNumber}</ONUM>
                        <CNAME>${order_header.CustomerName}</CNAME>
                        --></ftl:template>
        </ftl:freemarker>

                   <ftl:freemarker applyOnElement="order_line">
            <ftl:template>
                        <!--
                        <OLINE>
                            <ITEM>${.vars["order_line"]["ItemCode"]}</ITEM>
                            <QTY>${.vars["order_line"]["Quantity"]}</QTY>
                        </OLINE>
         --></ftl:template>
        </ftl:freemarker>
    </smooks-resource-list>
```

**The result What I am getting is below** i.e. the *Order_header* information `<ONUM>1</ONUM><CNAME>ABC</CNAME>` is appearing below the *Order_line* `<OLINE><ITEM>Item1</ITEM><QTY>2</QTY></OLINE>`. Actually Order_header should appear before Order_line. Please help!

```
<ORDERS>
    <STRUCTTYPE TYPE="1">
        <DEFAULTS>      
            <DIRECT>2</DIRECT>
            <DOCTYPE>ORDERS05</DOCTYPE>         
        </DEFAULTS>               
           <OLINE>
            <ITEM>Item1</ITEM>          
            <QTY>2</QTY>
           </OLINE>
           <OLINE>
            <ITEM>Item2</ITEM>
            <DESC>Item B</DESC>
            <QTY>1</QTY>
           </OLINE>
           <ONUM>1</ONUM>
          <CNAME>ABC</CNAME>      
           <OLINE>
            <ITEM>Item1</ITEM>          
            <QTY>2</QTY>
           </OLINE>
           <OLINE>
            <ITEM>Item2</ITEM>          
            <QTY>1</QTY>
           </OLINE>
            <OLINE>
            <ITEM>Item3</ITEM>          
            <QTY>1</QTY>
           </OLINE> 
          <ONUM>2</ONUM>
          <CNAME>XYZ</CNAME>           
    </STRUCTTYPE>
</ORDERS>
```

Comment: Can you create an execution report? It should tell you the order in which things are happening. My guess is that the applyOnElement (selector) is "order_header", causing it to be applied at the end.

Comment: Thanks Tom, any suggestion on converting without order_header?